# Could this be a design patent infringement?

Tags: patent-infringement, design-patent, design

I have a product that I am at the last stages of importing and have stumbled on a another product of similar design that is currently in application (29598689) of a design patent.

As the product itself is generic across the board, I am not sure if I would be infringing such a patent if approved.

Would my design that is currently manufactured by a number of companies and sold in parts of Asia infringe the relating applicants design? Photos attached & links below.

**My suppliers product:**http://www.organicfactory.co.kr/product/list.html?cate_no=69

**Patent pending product:** [https://www.amazon.com/Toddler-Travel-DMoose-16-Inch-13-Inch/dp/B01N2YJYEY/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1498095371&sr=8-1-spons&keywords=car+seat+travel+tray&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N2YJYEY)

Thanks
[image: Patent Pending product]

[image]

Comment: Specific infringement issues should be discussed with an attorney. We don't provide legal advice here

Comment: Could you link to the application?  As DonQuiKong says, we can't provide a legal opinion, but we can help you interpret the application.

Comment: I couldn't find the application. When I tried it on the US Public Pair site I get that it is either not available or an incorrect number. No good searching for it on patents.google.com either.

Comment: Can you apply/be issued for a design patent when the actual design is more of a functional feature? For example the curve at the base of the product pictured. It is more of a function as it "wraps" around the body of a child when positioned. This curve is commonly used in most trays.